# Laravel avoid relationship query on laravel after object creation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How to avoid querying relationship after object creation?

```php
$store = new Store();
$store->name = 'Store 1';
$store->save();

return response()->json($store->products());
```

Laravel is querying products table. I would like to avoid that since I know there is none. This is just an example.

`return response()->json([]);` is not an option. In real world I really need to use `$store->products()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `wasRecentlyCreated` property of model to identify if the model was inserted during the current request lifecycle.

```
$data = $store->wasRecentlyCreated ? [] : $store->products();
```